# Installation problem with Vega visualization grammar on Ubuntu

Tags: installation, yarnpkg, vega, incompatibility

I am trying to install vega on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS but having difficulties with `yarn add` command in order to install vega.

Output of command

```
E5450:~/Downloads/vega-master$ yarn add vega
yarn add v1.22.4
error Running this command will add the dependency to the workspace root rather than the 
workspace itself, which might not be what you want - if you really meant it, make it 
explicit by running this command again with the -W flag (or --ignore-workspace-root-check).
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
E5450:~/Downloads/vega-master$ yarn -W add vega
yarn add v1.22.4
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info fsevents@1.2.12: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.12" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding 
it from installation.
error dtslint@3.4.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version 
">=10.0.0". Got "8.10.0"
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

I cannot find anything regarding this error. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running `yarn` command given at vega github page, I ran `yarn --ignore-engines` to install `vega`. This worked fine.